# Using Google+ Sign-In To Authenticate Calls to App Engine Backend

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-plus, google-cloud-endpoints

So I followed the QuickStart App (Web), for adding a Google+ Sign-In button as described in their documentation here: https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button

I got that part working fine and dandy, locally as well as deployed to App Engine.

Now I want to take advantage of the opportunity that the Google+ Sign-In has provided, to make authenticated calls to a backend *EndPoint* in a similar manner outlined here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_js

Is this possible? I was wondering which part would the Google+ authentication "merge" in this flow, such that I do not have to call

```
gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: CLIENT_ID,
scope: SCOPES, immediate: mode},
authorizeCallback);
```

again, since I got my user logged in already using Google+ Sign-In!

Also, a couple of observations in my experiments to make these 2 work together:

1.) I have to "import" 2 similarly looking scripts, namely:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init">
```

for the OAuth2 "style", as well as

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js"></script>
```

([docs](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button))

OR

```
<script src="https://plus.google.com/js/client:plusone.js"></script>
```

([Github sample](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-javascript))

for Google+

2.) Both of them have callbacks when loaded, and I don't see how they could "merge" somewhere

3.) Anyways, I tried to run them both, and at some point, invoke and EndPoint method. The *user* parameter is null.

I am wondering if this is actually doable, or maybe I am just wasting my time in this effort? Logging in a user using Google+ potentially offers a few more features for an app.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this problem resolved by finding, and checking out the [Tic Tac Toe example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-java) which uses Google+ Sign-in method, to connect to the app's Google Cloud *[EndPoint](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/auth)*, and then as the example shows, call a method that requires authorization.

[The documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_js#Java_Adding_authentication_support_with_OAuth_20), using the Tic Tac Toe example threw me off, as it was using "plain OAuth", compared to the Tic Tac Toe example in Github, which was probably updated to use Google+ signin.

Anyway, I found it pretty smooth and simple actually. When the Google+ Sign-in callback executes with a successful authentication, you can now load your api and go from there. For example,

```
function signinCallback(authResult) {
  if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
    // Update the app to reflect a signed in user
    // Hide the sign-in button now that the user is authorized, for example:

    document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');

    // we are now authenticated at this point, and we can load our
    // Google Cloud Endpoints
    gapi.client.load(apiName, apiVersion, apiCallback, apiRoot);


  } else {
    // Update the app to reflect a signed out user
    // Possible error values:
    //   "user_signed_out" - User is signed-out
    //   "access_denied" - User denied access to your app
    //   "immediate_failed" - Could not automatically log in the user
console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
  }
}
```

After that, when my Google Cloud EndPoint API method gets called, it now receives a user object instead of being null as before.

```
    /**
 * This inserts a new <code>Payload</code> object.
 *
 * @param payload The object to be added.
 * @return The object to be added.
 */
@ApiMethod(name = "insertPayload")
public MapPackage insertPayload(Payload payload, User user) throws OAuthRequestException {
    // Implement this function

    LOG.info("Calling insertPayload method");
    if (user == null) {
        LOG.warning("User is null!");
    } else {
        //YEHEEY!!!!
        LOG.warning("User ID:" + user.getUserId());
        LOG.warning("User AuthDomain:" + user.getAuthDomain());

        LOG.warning("User nickname:" +user.getNickname());
        LOG.warning("User fedId:" +user.getFederatedIdentity());
        LOG.warning("User email:" +user.getEmail());
    }

    return payload;
}
```

Another thing to note, the minimum *scope* that got it working was

```
email
```

You should be referring to this same scope(s) in your backend API Signature as well as your HTML+Javascript client. For example, in Backend API annotation:

```
import javax.inject.Named;

/**
 * An endpoint class we are exposing
 */
@Api(name = "yourservicename",
    version = "v1",
    scopes = { https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login },
    clientIds = {Constants.WEB_CLIENT_ID, Constants.DEBUG_ANDROID_CLIENT_ID, Constants.PROD_ANDROID_CLIENT_ID},
    audiences = {Constants.ANDROID_AUDIENCE},
    namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "backend.yourappname.yourcompany.com",
            ownerName = "backend.yourappname.yourcompany.com",
            packagePath = ""))
```

HTML markup:

```
<span id="signinButton">
  <span
    class="g-signin"
    data-callback="signinCallback"
    data-clientid="YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
    data-requestvisibleactions="http://schema.org/AddAction"
    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">
  </span>
</span>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Google+ Photohunt sample in Java](https://developers.google.com/+/photohunt/java). This app shows you how to build an app on top of Google App Engine with a RESTful client.